# Custom LWC component doesn't appear in the community

Tags: lightning-web-components, community

I have a custom lwc component with configuration like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>50.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
    </targets> 
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

However, I don't see this component in the community builder.
Strangely , no custom components appear in the community, though there are few which are being used.
Any idea what might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I do not notice anything off with your XML configuration.

If you "Strangely" do not see any other of the components that you normally would, consider one of the following:

- If in a Scratch Org, might be a problem with the scratch org itself, try spinning a new one up.
- If this is happening in production, contact support if the issue does not resolve itself any time soon.

Comment: It's a non-scratch org and a developer sandbox